# javascript logic issue count of positions of visiting

Tags: javascript

I have long string with letters

```
< - means left
> - means right
^ means up
V - means down
```

I start at position in the middle of huge field, start walking according the directions(the long string). how many positions it visit more than once. 
the input is like

```
v<><^^v^^v<^^<>><>vv<<>><<>>v>^v^<<>>vv^>vv>^<>^><^vv^>>^v^<^^>^<<v^><v^^><>^^v>^v>v^<v^>^^v<v^v>^^<>v><<<<>^>v>^<><^<^vv<>vv^<>v^vv^^^^>v^<v<><>>^<<<<^^^v^^^>v^^^<v<^^<<^<<>><<<<<v>^vv^<><<^>>>^^<vv>>^^^^vv<v<>vv<^>v>>v^^>v<>^^<>>><<<v<<<>>v<<vv^<<^^<><v^<>>^<<><<^v^<^v>^>^v^v<v><<>>^<vv^<>>>v>>>v><>vv>v<v>vv><^^v><v<>v><^>v<>v><>^<^^<^^v<^vv^<<>^^vv<<^<>>><^^<v^>^><^<<^>>v^>>>><^^>v^^>vv><^^><>>>^>>v^^<<>><<^^<^<>><>v>>^v>v^^<<v<vv<vv^<<^><<v<><><<><^^<>v>^vvv><v>^v>^>>>>^^v^<><<vv>>v><vv<<v>><^<>^^v<^<vv>^<<v<^v<^v^^<<vv^^>v>>>^<^^v^vv>>^<^<^v^<^v<><<^<v<^>^^>^^<^>v<<^v^v><v<v<v<>>>^vv><>>><<^>^>^<^vvv^^<<v>>v><<v^^><v<vv^<v^>>v<^<>v^>><^><^>^<^>>^>^>>vv>v^v<vv<>v^<v^^vv<^>>vv<^>^>>v^v^v<<v<><v^v<^^>><<<^><<<>^vv<vv<^^v<vv<<v^^<<><>v^>v<>>^^^^^^^^>^<^^>vvv^<<<<<v^>^v>>>v<><v<^v>v^<^^^<<><<>vv<v>^vv<<><<^v<<<^v>^>^^><><>^>vv><>^vvv<^^vv^<>^<^<><^<^v^^<v^>v><vv><v^v>vv><>^^^<<><^>v<^><^^^^<^^v>^>v^<v^<v^v<^<vvvv>^^^^^>^^<^^^v^^><v^^^^<<vv<<vvvv><<>vvv>>^<vvv>v^>^><<vv^^>>^v^<^<vv^^>>^^>v^><><^>^v^>^><^^^<^v^v<<v>v^^v>>v<>>>^vv><^<<>^v>>^>>^^<v>>^v>v<^<>^^>v^><>v^>^>^>v<v^^<^>vvvv<v<<v^^>>v<^<^^>v><v<v><>v>^v^v>><^<>vv^v<>v^^<^<vv<<<<>>^<^^<>v<v>>><^>>>><><v^^v^>>v>v><v>^><vv<>^vv>vv>^<>^^><^vvvv^><<^>>^v>v>v^>^><^^^<^>^>><^>vv^^v<>^vv>>^^<<>>><<vvv<v<>^^<^
```

i wrote in js

```
let str = "v<><^^v^^v<^^<>><>vv<<>><<>>v>^v^<<>>vv^>vv>^<>^><^vv^>>^v^<^^>^<<v^><v^^><>^^v>^v>v^<v^>^^v<v^v>^^<>v><<<<>^>v>^<><^<^vv<>vv^<>v^vv^^^^>v^<v<><>>^<<<<^^^v^^^>v^^^<v<^^<<^<<>><<<<<v>^vv^<><<^>>>^^<vv>>^^^^vv<v<>vv<^>v>>v^^>v<>^^<>>><<<v<<<>>v<<vv^<<^^<><v^<>>^<<><<^v^<^v>^>^v^v<v><<>>^<vv^<>>>v>>>v><>vv>v<v>vv><^^v><v<>v><^>v<>v><>^<^^<^^v<^vv^<<>^^vv<<^<>>><^^<v^>^><^<<^>>v^>>>><^^>v^^>vv><^^><>>>^>>v^^<<>><<^^<^<>><>v>>^v>v^^<<v<vv<vv^<<^><<v<><><<><^^<>v>^vvv><v>^v>^>>>>^^v^<><<vv>>v><vv<<v>><^<>^^v<^<vv>^<<v<^v<^v^^<<vv^^>v>>>^<^^v^vv>>^<^<^v^<^v<><<^<v<^>^^>^^<^>v<<^v^v><v<v<v<>>>^vv><>>><<^>^>^<^vvv^^<<v>>v><<v^^><v<vv^<v^>>v<^<>v^>><^><^>^<^>>^>^>>vv>v^v<vv<>v^<v^^vv<^>>vv<^>^>>v^v^v<<v<><v^v<^^>><<<^><<<>^vv<vv<^^v<vv<<v^^<<><>v^>v<>>^^^^^^^^>^<^^>vvv^<<<<<v^>^v>>>v<><v<^v>v^<^^^<<><<>vv<v>^vv<<><<^v<<<^v>^>^^><><>^>vv><>^vvv<^^vv^<>^<^<><^<^v^^<v^>v><vv><v^v>vv><>^^^<<><^>v<^><^^^^<^^v>^>v^<v^<v^v<^<vvvv>^^^^^>^^<^^^v^^><v^^^^<<vv<<vvvv><<>vvv>>^<vvv>v^>^><<vv^^>>^v^<^<vv^^>>^^>v^><><^>^v^>^><^^^<^v^v<<v>v^^v>>v<>>>^vv><^<<>^v>>^>>^^<v>>^v>v<^<>^^>v^><>v^>^>^>v<v^^<^>vvvv<v<<v^^>>v<^<^^>v><v<v><>v>^v^v>><^<>vv^v<>v^^<^<vv<<<<>>^<^^<>v<v>>><^>>>><><v^^v^>>v>v><v>^><vv<>^vv>vv>^<>^^><^vvvv^><<^>>^v>v>v^>^><^^^<^>^>><^>vv^^v<>^vv>>^^<<>>><<vvv<v<>^^<^"

require('loadash')
let newStr = str.split('');
let newArray = []
let x =0, y=0;
let countNum = 0;
newStr.map((c)=>{
    switch(c){
        case '^':{
            y = y+1;
            break;
        }
        case 'v':{
            y = y-1;
            break;
        }
        case '>':{
            x = x+1;
            break;
        }
        case '<':{
            x = x-1;
            break;
        }
        default:{
            console.log("error input")
        }

    }
        let tempEntry = {y:y,x:x}
        let exist = _.findIndex(newArray, (o) => { return _.isMatch(o, tempEntry) });
        if(exist>-1){
            countNum = countNum +1;
        }else{
            newArray.push(tempEntry)
        }


    })
    console.log(newArray)
console.log("count is", countNum);
```

but it return me wrong answer , not what expected. did I do something wrong?

Comment: What does it return and what are you expecting it to return? When I run it, I get `Uncaught ReferenceError: _ is not defined`.

Comment: Why function map to loop? What's your expected result?

Comment: Obsidian Age you need to install loadash because that

Comment: Ele i dont know what expected result, its logic question

Comment: Wait, you wrote this *not what expected*

Comment: Yes, i need to know how many positions it visit thanmore once

Answer (score 1):

You didn't import lodash.
https://lodash.com

```
npm i --save lodash
```

Comment: This is wrong because the OP is using lodash for sure without any problem, further, how do you know s/he's using NodeJs?

Comment: I did import, i edit the post. The code rut but not return expected result. Its logic question i dont know what result should be

Answer (score 1):

First, in your code you must use:

```
const _ = require('lodash');
```

Answer (score 1):

So I know you didn't really ask for a code review, but I think the whole thing can be much more succinct, which will make it easier for you to debug. And you don't really need loadash. So consider this just a different way to approach your problem.

```js
// move in a counter-clockwise square twice
const str = '<<^^>>vv<<^^>>vv'

// map symbols to vectors
const directions = {'v':[0, -1], '^':[0, 1], '>': [1,0], '<':[-1,0] }

// helper function to add vectors
const addPoints = (p1, p2) => [p1[0] + p2[0], p1[1]+ p2[1]]

let result = str.split('').reduce((a, c) => {
    let vector = directions[c] // lookup vector
    a.current = addPoints(a.current, vector) // add it to current position to get new current pos

    // turn vector into a string that we can use as an object key
    let visited_key = a.current.join(',') 
    
    // how many times have we visited this spot?
    // it will be undefined if first visit
    let count = a.visited[visited_key]
    
    // increment or set to 1 depending on whether we've been here
    a.visited[visited_key] = count ? count + 1 : 1
    return a
}, {current:[0,0], visited:{}})

console.log(result)
```

You should see that we visit 8 points twice (not counting the initial position), and end up back at the origin.

This creates on object were the keys are coordinate strings like `'-1, 2'` and the values are the number of times we've visited.

This is a bit more functional approach and might be faster for longer strings since you don't have to search an array at every step (although the speed difference will probably be negligible in practice).